# Swiper pagination, trigger js code on specific slide

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

I'm using [SwiperJS](https://swiperjs.com) for sliders.
I was wondering if it's possible to set  trigger js code on specific slide in Swiper?

**For example**, if the user is on second slide the background changes, it triggers JS code `getElementById("body");element.classList.add("some-class");`

This should also work with arrows, so maybe the question should be,

Answer (score 1):

There's [a bunch of events](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events) that comes with SwipeJS out of the box.

You can check `swiper.realIndex` after `slideChange` event to trigger something only on specific slide.

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  // And if we need scrollbar
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
  },
});

// Do something on slide #2 (note that index starts from 0)
swiper.on('slideChange', (sw) => {
  if (sw.realIndex === 1) {
    console.log(`Message seen only after changing to slide #${swiper.realIndex + 1}`);
  }
});
```

```css
.slide {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
.slide-1 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.slide-2 {
  background-color: pink;
}
.slide-3 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide slide-1">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide slide-2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"> 
      <div class="slide slide-3">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

  <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need.